# “For as long as possible” vs “as long as possible”

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

How do you distinguish in their usage the two expressions: “*for as long as possible*” and “*as long as possible*”?

In the latter expression, the *long* is,  probably, almost always an adverb.

However, when it comes to grammatically explaining the former *long*, it has to be a noun because there’s a preposition *for*, whereas the explanation doesn’t make sense because there’s an adverb *as* before the *long*, which suggests the *long* has to be at least an adverb or adjective (and in this phrase the *long* would be an adverb.)

So I’d thought the former expression is grammatically wrong and so I shouldn’t say that way.

But here is [a graph from Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20as%20long%20as%20possible%2C%20as%20long%20as%20possible%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20as%20long%20as%20possible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20long%20as%20possible%3B%2Cc0).  This means the two expressions have almost the same number of sources.  ([Here’s a graph by FumbleFingers in which the subtraction is already done](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+as+long+as+possible%2C%28as+long+as+possible%29-%28for+as+long+as+possible%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20as%20long%20as%20possible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28as%20long%20as%20possible%29%20-%20%28for%20as%20long%20as%20possible%29%3B%2Cc0), thank you.)

And I found a lot of sources of “*for as long as possible*” ([from linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-japanese/search?source=auto&query=as+long+as+possible&cw=351)):

> As life expectancy pushes into the late 70s for men and well into the 80s for women, ever more people want help in order to be able to live their lives to the full **for as long as possible**. [icsw-japan.or.jp]

> This is a milestone for people with Alzheimer's disease, their families, carers and society as the new ruling means that crucial treatment can be given earlier thereby helping to keep patients as
> independent as possible **for as long as a possible**. [eisai.com]

On the other hand, I also found a lot of examples of “as long as possible”:

> In this context, it will become increasingly essential to build the environment where (1) older people can continue independent living **as long as possible**, (2) they can  fulfill their lives even when they need assistance in daily living, (3) the quality of life (QOL) based on older people’s own decisions until the last stage can be ensured, and (4) the conditions can be acceptable to caregivers. [ilcjapan.org]

> Again, you have to shoot down the bad guys, pick up new guns and survive **as long as possible**. [33games.net]

I suspect that both expressions are possible and native speakers use them differently depending on the situation.

So I’d like to know the difference in usage.

I started to think about this question because an Australian corrected a sentence I wrote in this way:

*Before*:
I decided to deceive my children again in order for them to believe in something imaginary as long as possible.

*After*:
I decided to deceive my children again in order for them to believe in something imaginary **for** as long as possible.

(In this context, something imaginary refers to Santa Claus.)

Sorry for such a long question. Thank you.

Comment: Your NGram link isn't very informative, because the chart for "as long as possible" ***includes / double counts*** all hits for "for as long as possible". [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+as+long+as+possible%2C%28as+long+as+possible%29-%28for+as+long+as+possible%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20as%20long%20as%20possible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28as%20long%20as%20possible%29%20-%20%28for%20as%20long%20as%20possible%29%3B%2Cc0) a more useful chart, which ***subtracts*** totals for the latter from those of the former.

Comment: I *think* the only other thing worth saying here is that in [almost?] all contexts, leading ***for*** before ***as long as possible*** is effectively "optional". I can't imagine there's ever a context where including it or not could affect the meaning.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn’t know the function.   **Either way the conclusion that both have almost the same number is true**.   I had it because **by myself** I subtracted the lower from the upper.  Thank you for telling me that Ngram has such a useful function.

Comment: So, though **the *for* is optional**, I was told that it was **wrong** and I was corrected?

Comment: I'd say the fact that ***for*** is "optional" rather than "incorrect" here is a small but useful scrap of information for you. But perhaps the *big* lesson for you should be that you should seriously discount anything else said by whoever misinformed you! :) Note that I hesitate to post an actual "Answer" here myself, because I'm not aware of any specific grammatical rule that could be cited. That's why I had to put **[almost]** in brackets above - but perhaps someone else can either confirm that it should be **[all**]**, or provide an example where the preposition is ***not*** optional.

Comment: Yes, that’s a big lesson, and your belief is very sensible, thank you.  I had two feelings about the ***for***.  I was a little upset to be misinformed. And at the same time I was  interested in the fact that a seemingly incorrect expression is actually possible and even fairly common, and  the expression made a native speaker even think that a technically grammatically-correct expression was wrong, or less common.  So I wanted to know the reason, or how native speakers choose one from the two.

Comment: And FumbleFingers, you gave me an answer that it is optional in **almost all, or, perhaps, all** contexts. I’m very satisfied.  Thank you very much!